# how to get string between braces along with string without braces using awk

Tags: shell-script

My input is:

```
ABC_DFG_FRE
s(DFR_GHY_JUY)
BGR_KIU_PLO
s(VFR_KJU_MKJ)
```

output sholud be:

```
ABC_DFG_FRE
DFR_GHY_JUY   
BGR_KIU_PLO  
VFR_KJU_MKJ
```

Comment: Can you show us your script and what you have done so far?

Comment: Maybe `tr -dc '[A-Z_\n]'` if your goal can be restated as "Keep only capital letters and underscores and newlines"

Comment: @godlygeek, that would also keep the `[` and `]` characters in POSIX tr's (and possibly other characters in non-C locales). Better `tr -cd '[:upper:]\n'` or `LC_ALL=C tr -cd 'A-Z\n'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Ah, you're right!  I started with `sed` and switched to `tr` - my mistake, good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' 'NF>2{print $2;next}1' file
ABC_DFG_FRE
DFR_GHY_JUY
BGR_KIU_PLO
VFR_KJU_MKJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with sed:

```
sed 's/.*(//; s/).*//' file
```

or the more strict:

```
sed 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/' file
```